# How to colorize the 'x' in a cancel svg icon

Tags: css, svg

I am looking at this svg icon: https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/352263/cancel_icon

How do I give the x inside of the circle a color other than transparent?

[Screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/d476c3ae90fd11ec86d167c61d3e4178.png)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M24 4C12.95 4 4 12.95 4 24s8.95 20 20 20 20-8.95 20-20S35.05 4 24 4zm10 27.17L31.17 34 24 26.83 16.83 34 14 31.17 21.17 24 14 16.83 16.83 14 24 21.17 31.17 14 34 16.83 26.83 24 34 31.17z" fill="#b01e1e" class="fill-000000"></path>
    <path d="M0 0h48v48H0z" fill="none"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your icon path is a compound path: it contains 2 shapes: outer circle and the inner "cut out"  x.  You can tell it from the second `m` command in the `d`attribute. You can "decompose" the path in an editor like inkscape via "path/break apart" command to get 2 paths you can style individually. You can also do it in code by: converting the `d` path data string to absolute commands (e.g via https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor) and copy the 2. part (starting at 2. `M` to a new `<path>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different svg icon since your current svg does not have a `fill` property of the `X` part

This should help you out:
Change the `fill` property to be a `hex or rgba` color or a predefined color name, for eg. a `hex` color code of red is `#f00`

```html
<svg class="vector" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- `CIRCLE` background -->
  <path
    d="M20 0C8.95 0 0 8.95 0 20C0 31.05 8.95 40 20 40C31.05 40 40 31.05 40 20C40 8.95 31.05 0 20 0ZM30 27.17L27.17 30L20 22.83L12.83 30L10 27.17L17.17 20L10 12.83L12.83 10L20 17.17L27.17 10L30 12.83L22.83 20L30 27.17Z"
    fill="tomato"
  />
  
  <!-- `X` symbol -->
  <path
    d="M30 27.17L27.17 30L20 22.83L12.83 30L10 27.17L17.17 20L10 12.83L12.83 10L20 17.17L27.17 10L30 12.83L22.83 20L30 27.17Z"
    fill="pink"
  />
</svg>
```